# JasperReports - How to run a report using Remote JSON Data Report in Java

Tags: java, rest, jasper-reports

Folks,

I have a report created in Studio that uses the JSON File data provider pointing to a GET RESTful endpoint with query parameters. In Studio, the report works fine when parameters are passed. Now I am trying to generate the report from within a Java console app but don't really know how to make it run. If I pass straight JSON to it, it works well, but how to do I get it to call the REST endpoint? Do I need to call the endpoint in my code, get the JSON and then pass it in? I was hoping that JasperReports library would make the call. Below are the pertinent part of the project.. Hope someone can help.

**The Report definition file**

```xml
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
              name="Inventory01" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="df013db5-f76e-44d3-b0df-bcbc46d93160">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="InventoryByProduct"/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[products]]>
    </queryString>
    <parameter name="storeno" class="java.lang.String" evaluationTime="Early">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.http.data.url.parameter" value="store"/>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="locale" class="java.lang.String" evaluationTime="Early">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.http.data.url.parameter" value="locale"/>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="product" class="java.lang.String" evaluationTime="Early">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.http.data.url.parameter" value="product"/>
    </parameter>
```

The Java code

```java
InputStream employeeReportStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(reportFile);
jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(employeeReportStream);

Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("locale", "en");
parameters.put("product", "680680976804");
parameters.put("storeno", "260");

//************ HOW SHOULD I CREATE THE JsonDataSource OBJECT AND PASS IT TO THE LIBRARY TO EXECUTE?
//************ IF ds WERE A JSON DOCUMENT, IT PRINTS CORRECTLY, BUT I NEED IT TO CALL THE URL OF THE 
//************ RESTFUL ENDPOINT
//            JsonDataSource ds = new JsonDataSource(jsonDataStream);
//            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, ds);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to work. For those running into the same problem, below is the solution.

Put the definition of the Json Adapter in a directory within your project:
[project structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoWvv.png)

In the jrxml report definition:

```xml
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
              name="Inventory01" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="df013db5-f76e-44d3-b0df-bcbc46d93160">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="data/inventorydataadapter.xml"/>
```

Then in your Java code:

```java
            InputStream employeeReportStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(reportFile);
            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(employeeReportStream);

            Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("locale", "en");
            parameters.put("product", "680680976804");
            parameters.put("storeno", "260");

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters);

            JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputPdf));
            SimplePdfReportConfiguration reportConfig = new SimplePdfReportConfiguration();
            reportConfig.setSizePageToContent(true);
            reportConfig.setForceLineBreakPolicy(false);
            SimplePdfExporterConfiguration exportConfig = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
            exportConfig.setMetadataAuthor("Ali M");
            exportConfig.setEncrypted(true);
            exportConfig.setAllowedPermissionsHint("PRINTING");
            exporter.setConfiguration(reportConfig);
            exporter.setConfiguration(exportConfig);

            exporter.exportReport();
```

That's it!